# BigQuery not showing all columns from Excel

Tags: excel, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I added a column into my excel sheet, and when loaded in BigQuery, the newly added column is not showing. Please help.

I have tried reading LOL

Answer (score 0):

do you have specific sheet ranges to read in BigQuery, if yes, this could be the issue. you probably have to update the sheet ranges option in the table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZjoF.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).